# Use of undeclard identifier 'DBL_EPSILON'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

For detecting a 4 inch screen I use:

```
#define IS_4_INCH ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

It always worked but now the compiler gives the error "Use of undeclard identifier DBL_EPSILON". I also imported `#import <float.h>` but there is still this error. What can I do? Should I use some other macro to detect the a 4 inch screen?

Comment: That macro works just fine (and DBL_EPSILON *is* defined in float.h). There must be something else causing the error. - If it worked before then try to find out what you changed in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

adding on top

```
#import <float.h>
```

will do the trick, but still not sure why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

import float.h in your .pch file at the top

```
#import<float.h>

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```